# Label configure is not working as intended, after button command

Tags: tkinter, combobox, python-3.6, ttk

I am developing a GUI which will allow a user to select an item from the dropdown list, get that item and use it elsewhere in the code. This is not working quite well.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("Vibration Certificate Generator")
        self.minsize(640, 400)
        #self.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')
        self.AddMenu()
        self.selectDUT()

    def AddMenu(self):   
        self.dropMenu = Menu()
        self.config(menu=self.dropMenu)

        self.fileMenu = Menu(self.dropMenu, tearoff=0) #file drop down menu
        self.dropMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="New Project...", 
        command=self.doNothing)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Now...", command=self.doNothing)
        self.fileMenu.add_separator() #adds line
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.doNothing)

        self.editMenu = Menu(self.dropMenu, tearoff=0) #edit drop down menu
        self.dropMenu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=self.editMenu)
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=self.doNothing)
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=self.doNothing)
        self.editMenu.add_separator() #adds line
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=self.doNothing)
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=self.doNothing)
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=self.doNothing)
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=self.doNothing)

        #self.statusBar = ttk.Label(self, text="Generating a certificate for...")
        self.statusBar = ttk.Label(self, text="Generating a certificate for...")
        self.statusBar.grid(column=0,row=4)

    def clickedDUT(self):

        self.statusBar.configure(text="You Have Selected " + self.SelectedDUT.get())
        print(self.SelectedDUT.get())

    def doNothing(self):
        print("ok ok i won't...")

    def selectDUT(self):

        self.SelectedDUT = StringVar()
        #print(self.SelectedDUT.get())
        self.SelectDeviceUnderTest = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30, textvariable=self.SelectedDUT.get())
        self.SelectDeviceUnderTest['values'] = ("ACCELEROMETER", "VELOCITY TRANSDUCER", 
                                  "IMPEDANCE HEAD", "CONDTIONING AMPLIFIER", "VIBRATION ANALYSER", 
                                  "VIBRATION METER", "TRIAXIAL ACCELEROMETER")
        self.SelectDeviceUnderTest.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.SelectDeviceUnderTest.current(0)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Select your DUT:")
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.buttonDUT = ttk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.clickedDUT())
        self.buttonDUT.grid(column=2,row=0) 

root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

I want the `clickedDUT()` to update with the value from `SelectedDUT.get()` obtained from the Combobox list option, after clicking OK.

Comment: Thanks @giser_yugang, I am still new here and i'm learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two small parts that are wrong in your code. The first one is how you set the `textvariable` for your `Combobox`. You should pass the variable directly but not the `get` method:

```
    def selectDUT(self):

        self.SelectedDUT = StringVar()
        self.SelectDeviceUnderTest = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30, textvariable=self.SelectedDUT)
        ...
```

The second one is a common mistake that you executed the command `self.clickedDUT` instead of passing a reference in `self.buttonDUT`. Change to this:

```
self.buttonDUT = ttk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.clickedDUT) #drop the trailing ()
```

If you want `self.statusBar` to appear on the bottom, you have to set a weight to every row:

```
def AddMenu(self):
    ...

    for i in range(1,10):
        self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

    self.statusBar = ttk.Label(self, text="Generating a certificate for...")
    self.statusBar.grid(column=0,row=10,columnspan=2,sticky="w")
```

Comment: Thanks @Henry Yik, that solves the problem. I am new in Python and i'm still trying to find my way around. The last thing I wanted to do is to put the statusBar label at the bottom of the grid (last row). Any ideas?

Comment: Arguably this will not be the best way to structure your GUI since you are leaving a lot of empty spaces in between. But yes, it is doable.